# How can I call fragmentactivity in mainactivity (AppCompactActivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to access FragmentActivity in MainActivity (AppCompactActivity)

here is my FragmentActivity:

```
public class MainFragment extends FragmentActivity {

private Fragment contentFragment;
HomeFragment homeFragment;
ProductDetailFragment pdtDetailFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
            String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
            if (content.equals(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                         if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                    contentFragment = fragmentManager
                            .findFragmentByTag(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                }
            }
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
            homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            contentFragment = homeFragment;
        }
        } else {
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        switchContent(homeFragment, HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }
        }
```

Here is My MainActivity Which Extends AppcompactActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     //How to i use FragmentActivity in MainActivity
 }
```

Comment: MainFragment  is not a fragment but a Support activity for Fragment. you can switch between the activities but can't load them on top of each other it will happen only with fragments

Comment: This previous comment is referring to the fact that your class name is misleading. `MainFragment` is not in fact a Fragment at all, but an Activity, specifically a `FragmentActivity`. Also an `AppCompatActivity` is a direct extension of `FragmentActivity`, so you might want to use `AppCompatActivity` only

Answer (score 2):

Replay Your Code with This Code.

Fragment: Code.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

 private Fragment contentFragment;
 HomeFragment homeFragment;
ProductDetailFragment pdtDetailFragment;
View rootView;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share_trip, container, false);
    try {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
        String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
        if (content.equals(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                     if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                contentFragment = fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            }
        }
    }
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
        homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        contentFragment = homeFragment;
    }
    } else {
    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    switchContent(homeFragment, HomeFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return rootView;
    }`
```

MainActivity Code:

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 MainFragment fragment2 = new MainFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` `Activity` is its self an `Activity`.

You can not call `FragmentActivity` inside `Activity`.

If you want to use `FragmentActivity` then you can extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Or you can call `Fragment` only inside `Activity`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "call inside Activity". You can always make an Intent to "call" another Activity from another. Do you mean "display"?